# Newbie trying to use variable derived from a class in another function outside of the class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have built a class to take user input date and time to create a date time object.  I want to use that object in another function but struggling.  I am about 2 months into coding so on steep learning curve.  Have been reading and watching videos all week about classes but seem to keep getting tripped up in my own code

Tried several iterations but suspect its just some fundamental flaw in my thinking about this

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

class User_Input_Date():
    """This class asks the user for a month and a year.  It takes the answers and puts them into a date object where day has been assigned to the 1st bc designed to just output month and year."""
    def __init__(self):

        self.month_input = input('What was the month (1-12)').strip()
        if self.month_input in ['01', '1', 'Jan', 'January', 'jan', 'january']:
            self.month_input = 1
        elif self.month_input in ['02', '2', 'Feb', 'February', 'feb', 'february']:
            self.month_input = 2
        elif self.month_input in ['03', '3', 'Mar', 'March', 'mar', 'march']:
            self.month_input = 3
        elif self.month_input in ['04', '4', 'Apr', 'April', 'apr', 'april']:
            self.month_input = 4
        elif self.month_input in ['05', '5', 'May', 'may']:
            self.month_input = 5
        elif self.month_input in ['06', '6', 'Jun', 'June', 'jun', 'june']:
            self.month_input = 6
        elif self.month_input in ['07', '7', 'Jul', 'July', 'jul', 'july']:
            self.month_input = 7
        elif self.month_input in ['08', '8', 'Aug', 'August', 'aug', 'august']:
            self.month_input = 8
        elif self.month_input in [
                '09', '9', 'Sept', 'September', 'sept', 'september'
        ]:
            self.month_input = 9
        elif self.month_input in ['10', 'Oct', 'October', 'oct', 'october']:
            self.month_input = 10
        elif self.month_input in ['11', 'Nov', 'November', 'nov', 'november']:
            self.month_input = 11
        elif self.month_input in ['12', 'Dec', 'December', 'dec', 'december']:
            self.month_input = 12
        else:
            self.month_input = None
        self.year_input = int(input('What was the year?').strip())

    def Combined_User_Input_Date(self):
        combine_date_user_input_month_year = datetime.date(
            self.year_input, self.month_input, day=1)
        return combine_date_user_input_month_year.strftime("%m" + "-" + "%Y")



primary_bariatric_date = User_Input_Date()
print(primary_bariatric_date.Combined_User_Input_Date())


def test_class_output_in_another_function(primary_bariatric_date.Combined_User_Input_Date():
    print(str(primary_bariatric_date.Combined_User_Input_Date() + "passed the test")

test_class_output_in_another_function(primary_bariatric_date.Combined_User_Input_Date())
```

I get,

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~omz-software~Pythonista3/Documents/My Classes/User Input Date Class.py", line 50
    def test_class_output_in_another_function(primary_bariatric_date.Combined_User_Input_Date():
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: That's not the problem. Why do you repeat the `Combined_User_Input_Date()` over and over again? It's a function, you only call it once.

Comment: Ok, fair, the parens aren't actually the cause of *this* syntax error, but they will be the cause of the next one. This one is caused by attempting to access an object attribute in the argument section of the function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you keep repeating `Combined_User_Input_Date()` over and over again. Only call it once, it is a function. I think you either mistyped it or you are stuck in thinking about functional languages like haskell.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

class User_Input_Date():
    """This class asks the user for a month and a year.  It takes the answers and puts them into a date object where day has been assigned to the 1st bc designed to just output month and year."""
    def __init__(self):

        self.month_input = input('What was the month (1-12)').strip()
        if self.month_input in ['01', '1', 'Jan', 'January', 'jan', 'january']:
            self.month_input = 1
        elif self.month_input in ['02', '2', 'Feb', 'February', 'feb', 'february']:
            self.month_input = 2
        elif self.month_input in ['03', '3', 'Mar', 'March', 'mar', 'march']:
            self.month_input = 3
        elif self.month_input in ['04', '4', 'Apr', 'April', 'apr', 'april']:
            self.month_input = 4
        elif self.month_input in ['05', '5', 'May', 'may']:
            self.month_input = 5
        elif self.month_input in ['06', '6', 'Jun', 'June', 'jun', 'june']:
            self.month_input = 6
        elif self.month_input in ['07', '7', 'Jul', 'July', 'jul', 'july']:
            self.month_input = 7
        elif self.month_input in ['08', '8', 'Aug', 'August', 'aug', 'august']:
            self.month_input = 8
        elif self.month_input in [
                '09', '9', 'Sept', 'September', 'sept', 'september'
        ]:
            self.month_input = 9
        elif self.month_input in ['10', 'Oct', 'October', 'oct', 'october']:
            self.month_input = 10
        elif self.month_input in ['11', 'Nov', 'November', 'nov', 'november']:
            self.month_input = 11
        elif self.month_input in ['12', 'Dec', 'December', 'dec', 'december']:
            self.month_input = 12
        else:
            self.month_input = None
        self.year_input = int(input('What was the year?').strip())

    def Combined_User_Input_Date(self):
        combine_date_user_input_month_year = datetime.date(
            self.year_input, self.month_input, day=1)
        return combine_date_user_input_month_year.strftime("%m" + "-" + "%Y")



primary_bariatric_date = User_Input_Date()
print(primary_bariatric_date.Combined_User_Input_Date())


def test_class_output_in_another_function(primary_bariatric_date):
    print(str(primary_bariatric_date.Combined_User_Input_Date()) + "passed the test")

test_class_output_in_another_function(primary_bariatric_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer solves it but there is also a much cleaner way to write your code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

# You can use normal tuples instead of frozensets but
# frozensets will be faster.
SYNONYMS = {
    frozenset(('01', '1', 'Jan', 'January', 'jan', 'january')): 1,
    frozenset(('02', '2', 'Feb', 'February', 'feb', 'february')): 2,
    frozenset(('03', '3', 'Mar', 'March', 'mar', 'march')): 3,
    frozenset(('04', '4', 'Apr', 'April', 'apr', 'april')): 4,
    frozenset(('05', '5', 'May', 'may')): 5,
    frozenset(('06', '6', 'Jun', 'June', 'jun', 'june')): 6,
    frozenset(('07', '7', 'Jul', 'July', 'jul', 'july')): 7,
    frozenset(('08', '8', 'Aug', 'August', 'aug', 'august')): 8,
    frozenset(('09', '9', 'Sept', 'September', 'sept', 'september')): 9,
    frozenset(('10', 'Oct', 'October', 'oct', 'october')): 10,
    frozenset(('11', 'Nov', 'November', 'nov', 'november')): 11,
    frozenset(('12', 'Dec', 'December', 'dec', 'december')): 12,
}
class User_Input_Date():
    """
    This class asks the user for a month and a year.  It takes the
    answers and puts them into a date object where day has been assigned
     to the 1st bc designed to just output month and year.
    """
    def __init__(self):

        month_input = input('What was the month (1-12): ').strip()
        self.month = None
        for month_syn in SYNONYMS: # Now we can just iterate instead of a lot of ifs
            if month_input in month_syn:
                self.month = SYNONYMS[month_syn]
                break

        self.year_input = int(input('What was the year: ').strip())

    def Combined_User_Input_Date(self):
        # This will error is self.month is None or year is invalid
        new_date = datetime.date(self.year_input, self.month, day=1)
        return new_date .strftime("%m-%Y") # You dont need to use +

u = User_Input_Date()
print(u.Combined_User_Input_Date())
```

Testing:

```
What was the month (1-12): 2
What was the year: 2019
02-2019
```

Note that it is also considered good practice to not have any IO done within a class except for debugging, so you shouldn't use a `input(...)` within your class.

Comment: Appreciate the time you took to demonstrate this significantly more elegant solution.  In my scenario how would you have approached gettting user input for date.  Would you just repeat the code for user input over an over again associate with different variable for that particular date.  Thanks again.  Sorry to ask another question just trying to understand best practices

Comment: You can loop or do multiple input statements. At that point its preference, but do it outside the class and pass it into either the constructor or the method.  The goal is to serperate the GUI, from the control logic, from the data logic.